# concatenate error during model import

Tags: merge, keras, concatenation, shapes, tensor

I have this problem: I concatenate correctly some outputs from different conv  layers. I train the model. Everything is fine up to the training. I save json model and weights.

When I load the model from another script using json API, I have this error:

ValueError: `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 12, 12, 512), (None, None, None, 512)]

This happens only when I import the saved model.
More details: I have an output from a Conv2 (12, 12, 512) and from another one that matches. The proof is the fact that I can train without any problem (and actually I plot the summary and all the output_shape are correctly defined... no 'None' in shapes but the batch size).
I also tried to add in keras.json image_data_format. But I still have this issue.
I use keras '2.1.2' and tensorflow '1.2.0'. I use the functional API of keras.
Any suggestions?

Comment: how are you saving and loading your model?

Comment: Please post your code first

Comment: I tried to save with keras API, in json, in yaml, and then weights... nothing worked properly. My solution was to isolate the model in another script, save only the weights, then reload the weights after importing the same model from the script. Unfortunately, I can't share the code :(